# Populating an array using inline variables

Tags: powershell

I generally use the following format when I populate a script with variables:

```
$string = ("Hi my name is {0} and I live in {1}, {2}." -f $username,$usercity,$userstate)
```

However this doesn't seem to work with an array, or I might be getting the syntax completely wrong:

```
$Arguments = @("/Settings:{0}", "/Tests:{1}", "/output:{2}" -f $TestSetting,$TestList,$Output)
```

When I output the results of that association, it all comes out as one string (with the substitution correct). If I look at the `Count`, it is 1. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each value in the array needs to be it's own expression with it's own operator:

```
$Arguments = @(("/Settings:{0}" -f $TestSetting), ("/Tests:{0}" -f $TestList), ("/output:{0}" -f $Output))
```

Comment: another way: `$arguments = ("/Settings:{0}","/Tests:{1}","/output:{2}" -f $TestSetting,$TestList,$Output)-split ' '`

Comment: To clarify the reason, it's because **-f** takes a string on the left side, not an array. The reason Micky Balladelli's suggestion works is only because the array on the left is dynamically converted to a string, and converting an array to a string concatenates the elements with spaces. It's essentially the same as `$arguments = ("/Settings:{0} /Tests:{1} /output:{2}" -f $TestSetting,$TestList,$Output) -split ' ' `.  The OP's code sets **$Arguments** to an array with a single string element, for that very reason: the **-f** operator causes the array on the left to be converted into a string.